# VB.NET Predicate Array Find

Tags: vb.net, arrays, find, predicate

How would I convert the following to a VB.NET predicate using Array.Find?

```
Private Function FindCulture(ByVal Code As String) As Globalization.CultureInfo
    '
    Dim AllCultures As Globalization.CultureInfo() = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    '
    For Each Culture As Globalization.CultureInfo In AllCultures
        If Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName = Code Then
            Return Culture
        End If
    Next
    '
    Return Nothing
    '
End Function
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Private Function FindCulture(ByVal Code As String) As Globalization.CultureInfo
    Dim AllCultures As Globalization.CultureInfo() = Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultures(Globalization.CultureTypes.AllCultures)
    Return Array.Find(AllCultures, Function(s) s.TwoLetterISOLanguageName = Code)
End Function
```